# Get Last week date of a date in yyyymmdd in Sybase SQL server

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table where a date is stored in the format of :  yyyymmdd in Sybase Adapative SQL server.

I would like to get the last week date based on the date stored in above table.

For example, if date stored is 20200430 -- Output has to be 20200423

For example, if date stored is 20200605 -- Output has to be 20200528

Please help me how can we do this.

Comment: Since this is not in proper date format and is  in yyyymmdd - I am stuck up on how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to subtract 7 days?

```
dateadd(day, -7, datecol)
```

Of course, if your date is actually a string, you need to convert to a date.  Your format should be fine for `cast(stringcol as date)`.